# Ограничение скорости входящего/исходящего трафика определённому приложению

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

можно ли на Python на windows ограничить скорость входящего или исходящего трафика определенному приложению(через pid процессы или точному пути до него)?

Comment: Ранее был схожий вопрос для [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1169370/). Возможно WinPcap-драйвер помог бы. Однако ранее на вопрос о такой возможности, дали ответ: [нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654030/), хотя и сослались на возможность фильтрации обрабатываемой информации.

Comment: Я ставил фаервол от фрибсд для этого

Comment: Скорости надо ограничить самому питону или стороннему приложению?

Comment: я уже сделал чуть по-другому, через pydivert

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов, не знаю насколько он актуален. Пользовался лет 10 назад - работало.

http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/index-ru.html ставим фаерволл от freebsd на виндовс.

Через pipe правило делается ограничение скорости.

Comment: На Windows 10 не устанавливается WIPFW